# modal appearing with modal backdrop in side

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, bootstrap-modal

I am new to html and trying to implement bootstrap modal dialog but modal backdrop(Not sure about the exact name) is appearing on left side of it ,how do i resolve this

[image: modal with backdrop]

I have already tried these :

1. z-index: 1;
2. data-backdrop="false"
3. Adding to body with

```
$('#exampleModalLong').appendTo($('body'));
```

this is my modal :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document" id="modalDocument">
        <div class="modal-content" id="modalContent">
            <div class="modal-header" id="modalHeader">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the CSS i have configured with modal :

```
#exampleModalLong {
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
        width: 75%;
        height: 75%;
        background: aqua;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

method to display modal :

```
function displayModel(message) {
            $('#exampleModalLong').modal('show')
        }
```

Please help me resolve this ,
Note : modal backdrop width is equivalent to width of navbar which will be displayed on clicking hamburger icon

Comment: Could provide live working code example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the modal backdrop is appearing on the left side of the modal because of the CSS you have set for the modal.

Instead of positioning the modal absolutely, you can try positioning it fixed within the viewport. You can try the following CSS for the modal:

```
#exampleModalLong {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1050;
}
```

This will position the modal at the center of the viewport and set the `z-index` to a higher value than the backdrop. This should ensure that the backdrop is behind the modal.

Also, make sure that you have included the Bootstrap CSS and JavaScript files properly in your HTML code.

Comment: this does not change  the visibility of backdrop. It only  changed the position of dialog with margin .But what if I do not want to see backdrop at any all.